# How do I prevent my text from breaking the words to fit the page and instead just scale down the size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a home page that looks like this:

[image: 1]

but when I shrink the page or I am on mobile it looks like this:

[image: 2]

This is all within an `<h1>` tag and the styling currently looks like this:

```
h1 { 
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Coolvetica';
    font-weight: 400;

    img {
        width: 46px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        opacity: 0;
        height: auto;
        animation: rotateIn 1s linear both;
        animation-delay: 1.4s;
    }
}
```

I have tried playing around with the overflow, using `vw` instead of `px` for `font-size` and none of it does what I want it to do

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` should do it

Comment: Did you try white-space: pre-wrap along with word-break: break-all for h1?

Comment: you may try with responsive font size `font-size:8vw;` for your <h1> element https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue using `word-break: break-word;` style property.
Try following style

```css
h1 { 
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Coolvetica';
    font-weight: 400;
    word-break: break-word;

    img {
        width: 46px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        opacity: 0;
        height: auto;
        animation: rotateIn 1s linear both;
        animation-delay: 1.4s;
    }
}
```